# Dotnet restore error "error NU3004: The package is not signed."

Tags: .net-core

I am getting error while doing Dotnet restore in AWS codebuild "error NU3004: The package is not signed." But I am not getting same error if I will do Dotnet restore locally.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What is the package that you are seeing this issue with? Can you create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which you can share with us?

Comment: I am getting error like this.
C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src334487811\src\src\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj : error NU3004: The package is not signed. [C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src334487811\src\ProjectName.sln]

Comment: To clarify this, you're building a Nuget package from your own project and want to run it on AWS?

Comment: Yes for CI process, we use AWS code build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. For me It's fixed by adding  Nuget.exe and nuget.config(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) file to my project root folder.